# Vuejs reverseKey not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am following the documentation of reverseKey http://011.vuejs.org/api/filters.html#orderBy[enter link description here](http://011.vuejs.org/api/filters.html#orderBy)

Here is my code:

```
<div class="one-table-row row-with-data row" v-for="message in messages | orderBy orderKey reverse |filterBy searchKey | offset offset | limit perpage">

    // ...... other code

</div>
```

My ViewModel:

```
data: function(){
   return {
      // other vars....
      reverse: false
   }
}
```

Above does not reverse the `message` list

But if I use this:

```
<div class="one-table-row row-with-data row" v-for="message in messages | orderBy orderKey -1|filterBy searchKey | offset offset | limit perpage">

   // ...... other code

</div>
```

Keeping the ViewModel same, this works.

So why does using `reverse` (either as false or -1) instead of -1 inline does not work?(it should according to the documentation link given above).

Comment: Which version of vue.js you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you linked to is very old, it's for Vue 0.11, you seem to be using a newer version, I'm guessing >= 1.0 (because you're using `v-for` instead of `v-repeat`) and < 2.0 (because filters in directives were abandoned after that).

Anyway, the feature should be working as you described - here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qojw08qt/1/) with Vue 1.0.28. Keep in mind that `true`/`false` won't work (because your documentation link is old and doesn't apply), you have to use `-1`/`1`.

But if what you described is true and you really tried `-1`/`1` too, then your problem is obviously somewhere else so you will have to provide more code (or better yet, a working demo of your issue) if you want us to help.

Comment: Yes you seem to be correct. I am using vue 1.0.7 BTW. -1/1 works but true/false doesn't